# Is this plugin being loaded before file.php, subsequently not allowing me to use certain functions?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, core

I'm trying to use [`get_home_path()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path) in my plugin, however, I get a *`call to undefined function`* fatal error (running Wordpress 3.8).

I believe this would imply that my plugin is being loaded before *wp-admin/includes/file.php* where `get_home_path()` is located, right?

Is it just me, or is that a little odd? How can I make file.php load first so I can access this function?

The line of code that causes this issue (within my plugin) is:

```
register_theme_directory(get_home_path().'/material/views');
```

Comment: How do you call your plugin... the function that contains your register_theme_directory(). You probably need to find a different hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make sure everything required is loaded before plugins loads, use [plugins_loaded](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/plugins_loaded) hook and initialize your plugins its callback funtion. for example:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded',function(){
  // initialize your plugins here.
});
```

Comment: The plugins_loaded hook is too early for this case, actually. He should wait until admin_init, at least.